# Why is GraphPropertyDistribution[.] taking an infinite amount of time to run?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, code-review

This code is from the documentation:

```
dist[n_, k_] := 
 GraphPropertyDistribution[GlobalClusteringCoefficient[g], 
  g \[Distributed] DegreeGraphDistribution[ConstantArray[k, n]]];

SmoothHistogram[
 Table[RandomVariate[dist][34, k], 10], {k, 14, 18}], Automatic, 
 "PDF", Filling -> Axis
 ]
```

I have a very powerful computer but the above code is running continuously. I cannot get any output from it. Is this a bug or what?

Comment: `GraphPropertyDistribution` is over-ambitious. In the majority of cases there is no analytic result it could make use of. If you are going to do numerical sampling, it's better to do it manually so that you can keep partial result.

Comment: @Szabolcs: In fact, I found one of your answers many years ago and that answer was relevant to my problem. I was imagining that after many years passed, Mathematica made an improvement to solve that problem. It seems that they did not address this issue. Thanks for your confirmation.

Comment: Mathematica works for `\[ScriptCapitalD][n_, k_] := 
 GraphPropertyDistribution[GlobalClusteringCoefficient[g], 
  g \[Distributed] DegreeGraphDistribution[ConstantArray[k, n]]]
SmoothHistogram[
 Table[RandomVariate[\[ScriptCapitalD][34, k], 1000], {k, 5, 
   12}], Automatic, "PDF", Filling -> Axis]` but for larger `k` values, it does not work.